# Dynamically change the favicon

Tags: javascript, html

[This website](https://www.vesta.nl/) somehow can display the amount of items in the shopping cart on top of it's tab icon.

[image: counter in favicon]

(Click "in winkelmand" on any product)

How does it do it?

Comment: I could not see this. But you could "exchange" the favIcon.

Comment: Yup, I confirmed and that's exactly what they do. They use base64 image in the `rel="shortcut icon"` link

Comment: @AlonEitan base64 image was auto generate? It's a gif, you can see animation when reload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This website is using base64 image to display as favicon, like this

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="data:image/png;base64,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" type="image/png">
```

You can use [favico.js](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/) to achieve dynamic cart badge in favicon. **[DEMO](http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/example-simple/)**

This website uses WooCommerce for shopping cart functionality, you can refer following plugin to add dynamic favicon generation based on number of items in cart

[Woocomerce Favicon Cart Badge](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/woocomerce-favicon-cart-badge/trunk/woocommerce-cart-badge.php)